# Using the ternary operator instead of if/else?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have recently been learning about the ternary operator, and how it is a good shortcut instead of using if/else operator.

I've been practicing and this is a program that that configures what type of school someone should go to based on their age.

However, when I run the code, it is not working.

```
var age = 15;

function whichSchool(age) {
  return (age < 13) ? "Elementary School"
       : (age >= 13 && age <= 18) ? "Secondary School"
       : (age > 18) ? "University"
}

console.log(whichSchool(15))
```

It says: unexpected token {.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You have an extra `?` at the end with no corresponding `:`. You need both for a ternary operator.

Comment: Remove the `(age > 18) ?` part, it's expecting the "else" of the last ternary, which isn't there.

Comment: Since you have no cap... last conditional is pointless anyway

Comment: The correct error is on chrome: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", and on FF "SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression", please read and describe the proper errors, it will help you understand what is wrong. "unexpected token {" makes no sense.

Comment: Also note you just found out why chaining ternaries can be a pain in the A**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary syntax is `conditional ? true : false`. You've combined multiple `if` conditional ternaries here, though no logic for if **none** of the conditionals are met. To correct this, add fallback behavior of `: false` after your final conditional:

```js
var age = 15;

function whichSchool(age) {
  return (age < 13) ? "Elementary School"
       : (age >= 13 && age <= 18) ? "Secondary School"
       : (age > 18) ? "University"
       : "None"
}

console.log(whichSchool(15))
```

Note that this `false` logic will never actually be met though with the combination of conditionals above (someone is either under 13, between 13 and 18 or over 18), and you'd be better off simply having `: "University"` as the default in this instance:

```js
var age = 15;

function whichSchool(age) {
  return (age < 13) ? "Elementary School"
       : (age >= 13 && age <= 18) ? "Secondary School"
       : "University"
}

console.log(whichSchool(15))
```

Comment: Because it's required to correctly validate. You could alternatively change the last line to simply be `: "University", and I'll update the answer to mention that :)

Comment: To make the code more concise, I'd `return age < 13 ? "Elementary School" 
     : age > 18 ? "University"
     : "Secondary School";` - I mean, you're chaining ternaries, so teh code is unreadable anyway, so why preserve an arbitrary order - there's no harm in checking < 13 then > 18 and everything else must be between the two :p